# If we use goo.gl for a link, will Google be the referrer for that link?

Tags: google, url, referrer, url-shorteners

For example, I can shorten `http://example.com` with Google URL shortener goo.gl. If I get clicks to the Google shortened URL `https://goo.gl/...`, will I see `goo.gl` as the referrer in the analytics for example.com?

Comment: Any answer on this yet?  I'm running into the same question.  Popular pages show a referer in GWT of "ow.ly/...." and the ow.ly URL resolves to the page in question.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about the goo.gl butI've been using bit.ly for quite some time and I don't se bitly as the referrer for the traffic received from those links.

I've also been using bit.ly for links with UTM parameters and the result is the same.